# Best way to compute the eigenvalues/polynomial of a $4\times 4$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

What is the fastest way to compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ or better, how do I prove that the characteristic polynomial is $t^2(t-2)^2$ ?

$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&-3&1&2\\-2&1&-1&2\\-2&1&-1&2\\-2&-3&1&4 \end{bmatrix}$

I know the most straightforward solution is simply $\det(\lambda I -A) = 0$ but it's not the fastest. Any suggestions?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial IS $\det(\lambda I - A)$. Why do you think computing this determinant it is not the fastest way?

Comment: @Gribouillis sure what I meant is, is there a fast way to compute this ? I tried to put this $det(\lambda I - A)$ into an upper triangular Matrix but I it got messy.

Comment: In the determinant, start by substracting line 2 from line 3, then add column 3 to column 2, you are left with  a 3x3 determinant. In this determinant, add column 2 to column 3, etc.

Comment: @Gribouillis but there's a $\lambda$ in there, ... or are you saying I can row reduce before subtracting $\lambda I$ ?

Comment: No, you must compute with the $\lambda$s in the matrix. But the steps above allow you to factor $\lambda$, then $\lambda - 2$ easily.

Comment: @Gribouillis so can I simplify the matrix before computing the determinant? I didn't know that.

Comment: No you can't. It's not what I said.

Comment: @Gribouillis what I mean is simplify the matrix that comes out from this $(\lambda I - A)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64862/discussion-between-gribouillis-and-leroy).

Comment: You’ve really got two different questions here. Verifying that some polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is rather different from computing it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete calculation of $\text{det} \left({\lambda} I-A\right)$ with the method I gave in the comments.
We first perform operations ${R}_{3}-{R}_{2} \rightarrow  {R}_{3}$ and ${C}_{2}+{C}_{3} \rightarrow  {C}_{2}$
on the rows and the columns of the determinant

$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}{\lambda}&3&{-1}&{-2}\\
2&{\lambda}-1&1&{-2}\\
2&{-1}&{\lambda}+1&{-2}\\
2&3&{-1}&{\lambda}-4
\end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{cccc}{\lambda}&3&{-1}&{-2}\\
2&{\lambda}-1&1&{-2}\\
0&{-{\lambda}}&{\lambda}&0\\
2&3&{-1}&{\lambda}-4
\end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{cccc}{\lambda}&2&{-1}&{-2}\\
2&{\lambda}&1&{-2}\\
0&0&{\lambda}&0\\
2&2&{-1}&{\lambda}-4
\end{array}\right|$$

We now have a ${3}\times{3}$ determinant, we do ${C}_{2}+{C}_{3} \rightarrow  {C}_{3}$, then
${R}_{2}-{R}_{3} \rightarrow  {R}_{2}$

$${\lambda} \left|\begin{array}{ccc}{\lambda}&2&{-2}\\
2&{\lambda}&{-2}\\
2&2&{\lambda}-4
\end{array}\right| = {\lambda} \left|\begin{array}{ccc}{\lambda}&2&0\\
2&{\lambda}&{\lambda}-2\\
2&2&{\lambda}-2
\end{array}\right| = {\lambda} \left|\begin{array}{ccc}{\lambda}&2&0\\
0&{\lambda}-2&0\\
2&2&{\lambda}-2
\end{array}\right|$$

It only remains a triangular ${2}\times{2}$ determinant.

$${\lambda} \left({\lambda}-2\right) \left|\begin{array}{cc}{\lambda}&2\\
0&{\lambda}-2
\end{array}\right| = {{\lambda}}^{2} {\left({\lambda}-2\right)}^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a fastest, widely applicable way to hand-calculate the characteristic polynomial. So, my advice is to stick with the old-fashioned and systematic way (i.e. to calculate $\det(xI-A)$) rather than wasting time on finding a shortcut that is efficient only in a few specific cases.

Nevertheless, in this particular example, it is quite obvious that the four columns of $A$ sum up to the zero vector. Also, the first and the last rows coincide in the second and the third elements. Therefore, if
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&1},
$$
then
$$
P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{2&0&0&0\\ 0&4&-2&0\\ 0&4&-2&0\\ -2&-3&1&0}
$$
is lower block-triangular. Hence the spectrum of $A$ consists of $2,0$ and the two eigenvalues of $B=\pmatrix{4&-2\\ 4&-2}$. $B$ is a singular $2\times2$ matrix of trace $2$. Hence its two eigenvalues are $0$ and the trace. Hence the result.